# Grooveshark closing connection early (httplib.BadStatusLine)

Tags: python, httplib2, grooveshark

I'm trying to connect to grooveshark. For this python is my language of choice. but i have hit a brick wall. it would seem that grooveshark recently changed part of their protocol, or i might have hit a limitation of python.

I am working "together" with JackTheRipper51 from github, he made this library for grooveshark: https://github.com/jacktheripper51/groove-dl
it's not actually a library, but i quickly recoded to be a library.

earlier this week it worked fine, and i was able to use it for my project. but 2 days ago it started failing on the getToken function, httplib started returning `httplib.BadStatusLine: ''` which from my research means that the server closed the connection early.

From this research i started looking at the javascript and flash source of grooveshark, but that didn't return anything of value. So i did what any sane person that spent 5 hours looking at decompiled actionscript without ever having coded a line in the stuff before would do, and blamed it on groovesharks server.

Specifically i figured that grooveshark might deny connections that feature the `Connection: close` header. I therefore decided to test it in the `REST Console` extension for Chrome.

I made the python script dump the json it was encoding, and i pastes that into Rest Console, hit POST and it returned fine, with the expected data. I was now certain that it wasn't impossible that i was right.

My next step was to code in httplib2 (as that supports `Connection: keep-alive`) which i have, but the problem persists.

I have tested in wireshark (removing the SSL in https, and it does send `Connection: keep-alive`, this causes grooveshark to respond, but with `https required`)

I have only modified small parts of the code.

Completely changed getToken()

```
def getToken():
    global staticHeader, _token
    post = {}
    post["parameters"] = {}
    post["parameters"]["secretKey"] = hashlib.md5(staticHeader["session"]).hexdigest()
    post["method"] = "getCommunicationToken"
    post["header"] = staticHeader
    post["header"]["client"] = "htmlshark"
    post["header"]["clientRevision"] = "20120312"
    header = {"User-Agent": _useragent, "Referer": _referer, "Content-Type":"application/json", "Cookie":"PHPSESSID=" + staticHeader["session"], "Connection":"keep-alive"}
    response, content = http.request("https://grooveshark.com/more.php?getCommunicationToken", "POST" ,body = json.JSONEncoder().encode(post), headers = header)
    print response
    #_token = json.JSONDecoder().decode(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=(StringIO.StringIO(conn.getresponse().read()))).read())["result"]
    #print _token
```

I added what the httplib2 initializes:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
```

I imported httplib2:

```
import httplib, httplib2
```

I also renamed the json constructors, simply because i wanted then more descriptive.

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Delusional Logic\Documents\GitHub\groove-dl\python\groove.py", line 141, in <module>
    getToken()
  File "C:\Users\Delusional Logic\Documents\GitHub\groove-dl\python\groove.py", line 51, in getToken
    response, content = http.request("https://grooveshark.com/more.php?getCommunicationToken", "POST" ,body = json.JSONEncoder().encode(post), headers = header)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1544, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1294, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1264, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1027, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
```

What is causing the BadStatusLine, and how can i fix it.

PS i know for a fact they had an 8 hour meeting the day before this broke, i bet you this was on the agenda.

UPDATE: JackTheRipper51 has informed me that this happens with all ssl request to grooveshark.com/more.php, no matter what you send. this makes me belive that it's python playing tricks on us.

UPDATE 2:

JackTheRipper51 just informed me that it is indeed python. Here's his post:

> I didn't need C at all. Prepare to be outraged. A simple

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "@jsontest" "https://grooveshark.com/more.php?getCommunicationToken" -v on a linux
```

> box got me a token... jsontest here being

```
{"header":{"client":"mobileshark","clientRevision":"20120227","privacy":0,"country":{"ID":63,"CC1":4611686018427388000,"CC2":0,"CC3":0,"CC4":0,"DMA":0,"IPR":0},"uuid":"BF5D03EE-91BB-40C9-BE7B-11FD43CAF0F0","session":"1d9989644c5eba85958d675b421fb0ac"},"method":"getCommunicationToken","parameters":{"secretKey":"230147db390cf31fc3b8008e85f8a7f1"}}
```

> Even when the json is not syntactically correct, it always returns at
>   least some headers! It's been Python all along...

The only question remaining is why is python doing this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been "resolved", or the cause has been found.

JackTheRipper submitted the error to python, where they confirmed that it was indeed a problem with ssl, more specifically openssl 0.9.8, that was causing the connection to time out.

Bug Report:
http://bugs.python.org/issue15082